# AWS ECS CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref, not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

when trying to run an AWS ECS task I am getting the following error:

`CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thing/1234567:latest": id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thing/1234567:latest: not found`

In the task definition the image is set as `id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thing/1234567` and is present in the ECR repository. I am not sure where the :latest is coming from, and I am wanting to point it the the image `id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thing/1234567` as opposed to `id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/thing/1234567:latest`.

I'm wondering if this is just a result of me not knowing how tags work. Can someone point me in the direction of where this :latest is coming from, and how to remove it to point to the image without the :latest that is present in the respository? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in ECR console what is the correct image url?

Comment: Each image has a tag. You can't point it to an image without a tag, since that would include all images in the repository. What tag does your desired image have?

Comment: This was failing for me due to a lack of permissions.  Uploading images required the following to work: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload, ecr:UploadLayerPart, ecr:CompleteLayerUpload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ooof. This was just me not understanding the url structure. Should have been pointing to the image thing:1234567 in the task definition as opposed to thing/1234567.

Comment: had same issue so targeted specific version `XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-flask-app:a2aa32179ae30b131a72cb847e61d5745415c6d9`

Answer (score 2):

Another stupid error: make sure the `image` and its `tag` you are pulling exist in `ecr`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you have your image pushed to ECR with the appropriate image tag (`latest` by default).

Add the required interface and gateway VPC endpoints -

- ECR Interface endpoints for making ECR images accessible to your ECS services.

  - `com.amazonaws.<region>.ecr.dkr`
  - `com.amazonaws.<region>.ecr.api`
- S3 Gateway endpoint for making the S3 (where ECR images are actually stored) accessible to ECS.

  - `com.amazonaws.<region>.s3`

Comment: this solved my problem, i just needed to know which subnet was associated with the endpoint and then it worked!